# Nested IF statement not working with Vendor Email Template - PHP Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Can you please help me see what I am doing wrong here?
When I cancel a booking and choose the option to refund the amount paid for some reason the BookingCancelled email blade template is not kicking off to the customer. Below is the full code of the email template.

```
<!--
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| BOOKING CANCELLED USER EMAIL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|  Available class objects to be used
|  $booking, $refund_status (boolean)
|
|
-->

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<!-- NAME: ANNOUNCE -->
<!--[if gte mso 15]>
<xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
<o:AllowPNG/>
<o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>{{ __('emails.booking_cancelled_subject', ['booking_id' => $booking->id]) }}</title>

<style type="text/css">
p{
margin:10px 0;
padding:0;
}
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
img,a img{
border:0;
height:auto;
outline:none;
text-decoration:none;
}
body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}
.mcnPreviewText{
display:none !important;
}
#outlook a{
padding:0;
}
img{
-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
table{
mso-table-lspace:0pt;
mso-table-rspace:0pt;
}
.ReadMsgBody{
width:100%;
}
.ExternalClass{
width:100%;
}
p,a,li,td,blockquote{
mso-line-height-rule:exactly;
}
a[href^=tel],a[href^=sms]{
color:inherit;
cursor:default;
text-decoration:none;
}
p,a,li,td,body,table,blockquote{
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
}
.ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font{
line-height:100%;
}
a[x-apple-data-detectors]{
color:inherit !important;
text-decoration:none !important;
font-size:inherit !important;
font-family:inherit !important;
font-weight:inherit !important;
line-height:inherit !important;
}
.templateContainer{
max-width:600px !important;
}
a.mcnButton{
display:block;
}
.mcnImage,.mcnRetinaImage{
vertical-align:bottom;
}
.mcnTextContent{
word-break:break-word;
}
.mcnTextContent img{
height:auto !important;
}
.mcnDividerBlock{
table-layout:fixed !important;
}
/*
@tab Page
//section Heading 1
@style heading 1
*/
h1{
/*@editable*/color:#000000;
/*@editable*/font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/*@editable*/font-size:40px;
/*@editable*/font-style:normal;
/*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
/*@editable*/line-height:150%;
/*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
/*@editable*/text-align:center;
}
/*
@tab Page
//section Heading 2
@style heading 2
*/
h2{
/*@editable*/color:#000000;
/*@editable*/font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/*@editable*/font-size:34px;
/*@editable*/font-style:normal;
/*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
/*@editable*/line-height:150%;
/*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
/*@editable*/text-align:left;
}
/*
@tab Page
//section Heading 3
@style heading 3
*/
h3{
/*@editable*/color:#000000;
/*@editable*/font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/*@editable*/font-size:22px;
/*@editable*/font-style:normal;
/*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
/*@editable*/line-height:150%;
/*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
/*@editable*/text-align:left;
}
/*
@tab Page
//section Heading 4
@style heading 4
*/
h4{
/*@editable*/color:#4e5e6a;
/*@editable*/font-family:Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
/*@editable*/font-size:20px;
/*@editable*/font-style:italic;
/*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
/*@editable*/line-height:125%;
/*@editable*/letter-spacing:normal;
/*@editable*/text-align:center;
}
/*
@tab Header
//section Header Container Style
*/
#templateHeader{
/*@editable*/background-color:{{ config('settings.primary_color') ? config('settings.primary_color') : '#007bff' }};
/*@editable*/background-image:none;
/*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*@editable*/background-position:center;
/*@editable*/background-size:cover;
/*@editable*/border-top:0;
/*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
/*@editable*/padding-top:11px;
/*@editable*/padding-bottom:11px;
}
/*
@tab Header
//section Header Interior Style
*/
.headerContainer{
/*@editable*/background-color:#transparent;
/*@editable*/background-image:none;
/*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*@editable*/background-position:center;
/*@editable*/background-size:cover;
/*@editable*/border-top:0;
/*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
/*@editable*/padding-top:0;
/*@editable*/padding-bottom:0;
}
/*
@tab Header
//section Header Text
*/
.headerContainer .mcnTextContent,.headerContainer .mcnTextContent p{
/*@editable*/color:#ffffff;
/*@editable*/font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/*@editable*/font-size:16px;
/*@editable*/line-height:150%;
/*@editable*/text-align:left;
}
/*
@tab Header
//section Header Link
*/
.headerContainer .mcnTextContent a,.headerContainer .mcnTextContent p a{
/*@editable*/color:#ffffff;
/*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
/*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
}
/*
@tab Body
//section Body Container Style
*/
#templateBody{
/*@editable*/background-color:#fafafa;
/*@editable*/background-image:none;
/*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*@editable*/background-position:center;
/*@editable*/background-size:cover;
/*@editable*/border-top:0;
/*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
/*@editable*/padding-top:51px;
/*@editable*/padding-bottom:51px;
}
/*
@tab Body
//section Body Interior Style
*/
.bodyContainer{
/*@editable*/background-color:#transparent;
/*@editable*/background-image:none;
/*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*@editable*/background-position:center;
/*@editable*/background-size:cover;
/*@editable*/border-top:0;
/*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
/*@editable*/padding-top:0px;
/*@editable*/padding-bottom:0px;
}
/*
@tab Body
//section Body Text
*/
.bodyContainer .mcnTextContent,.bodyContainer .mcnTextContent p{
/*@editable*/color:#000000;
/*@editable*/font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/*@editable*/font-size:16px;
/*@editable*/line-height:150%;
/*@editable*/text-align:left;
}
/*
@tab Body
//section Body Link
*/
.bodyContainer .mcnTextContent a,.bodyContainer .mcnTextContent p a{
/*@editable*/color:#007bff;
/*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
/*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
}
/*
@tab Footer
//section Footer Style
*/
#templateFooter{
/*@editable*/background-color:{{ config('settings.secondary_color') ? config('settings.secondary_color') : '#4e5e6a' }};
/*@editable*/background-image:none;
/*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*@editable*/background-position:center;
/*@editable*/background-size:cover;
/*@editable*/border-top:0;
/*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
/*@editable*/padding-top:15px;
/*@editable*/padding-bottom:15px;
}
/*
@tab Footer
//section Footer Interior Style
*/
.footerContainer{
/*@editable*/background-color:#transparent;
/*@editable*/background-image:none;
/*@editable*/background-repeat:no-repeat;
/*@editable*/background-position:center;
/*@editable*/background-size:cover;
/*@editable*/border-top:0;
/*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
/*@editable*/padding-top:0;
/*@editable*/padding-bottom:0;
}
/*
@tab Footer
//section Footer Text
*/
.footerContainer .mcnTextContent,.footerContainer .mcnTextContent p{
/*@editable*/color:#FFFFFF;
/*@editable*/font-family:'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
/*@editable*/font-size:12px;
/*@editable*/line-height:150%;
/*@editable*/text-align:center;
}
/*
@tab Footer
//section Footer Link
*/
.footerContainer .mcnTextContent a,.footerContainer .mcnTextContent p a{
/*@editable*/color:#FFFFFF;
/*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
/*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
.templateContainer{
width:600px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote{
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
body{
width:100% !important;
min-width:100% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnRetinaImage{
max-width:100% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnImage{
width:100% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnCartContainer,.mcnCaptionTopContent,.mcnRecContentContainer,.mcnCaptionBottomContent,.mcnTextContentContainer,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer,.mcnImageGroupContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftImageContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer,.mcnImageCardLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnImageCardRightTextContentContainer,.mcnImageCardLeftImageContentContainer,.mcnImageCardRightImageContentContainer{
max-width:100% !important;
width:100% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer{
min-width:100% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnImageGroupContent{
padding:9px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter .mcnTextContent,.mcnCaptionRightContentOuter .mcnTextContent{
padding-top:9px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnImageCardTopImageContent,.mcnCaptionBottomContent:last-child .mcnCaptionBottomImageContent,.mcnCaptionBlockInner .mcnCaptionTopContent:last-child .mcnTextContent{
padding-top:18px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnImageCardBottomImageContent{
padding-bottom:9px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnImageGroupBlockInner{
padding-top:0 !important;
padding-bottom:0 !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnImageGroupBlockOuter{
padding-top:9px !important;
padding-bottom:9px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentColumn{
padding-right:18px !important;
padding-left:18px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcnImageCardLeftImageContent,.mcnImageCardRightImageContent{
padding-right:18px !important;
padding-bottom:0 !important;
padding-left:18px !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
.mcpreview-image-uploader{
display:none !important;
width:100% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Heading 1
@tip Make the first-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
*/
h1{
/*@editable*/font-size:30px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:125% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Heading 2
@tip Make the second-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
*/
h2{
/*@editable*/font-size:26px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:125% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Heading 3
@tip Make the third-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
*/
h3{
/*@editable*/font-size:20px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Heading 4
@tip Make the fourth-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
*/
h4{
/*@editable*/font-size:18px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Boxed Text
@tip Make the boxed text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
*/
.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent p{
/*@editable*/font-size:14px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Header Text
@tip Make the header text larger in size for better readability on small screens.
*/
.headerContainer .mcnTextContent,.headerContainer .mcnTextContent p{
/*@editable*/font-size:16px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Body Text
@tip Make the body text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
*/
.bodyContainer .mcnTextContent,.bodyContainer .mcnTextContent p{
/*@editable*/font-size:16px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
}

}   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
/*
@tab Mobile Styles
//section Footer Text
@tip Make the footer content text larger in size for better readability on small screens.
*/
.footerContainer .mcnTextContent,.footerContainer .mcnTextContent p{
/*@editable*/font-size:14px !important;
/*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
}

}</style></head>
<body>
<center>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
<!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" id="templateHeader" data-template-container>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<![endif]-->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="headerContainer"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
<tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding:0px" class="mcnImageBlockInner">
<table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;">


<img align="left" alt="{{ config('settings.business_name') }}" src="{{ asset('images/logo-light.png') }}" width="250" style="max-width:500px; padding-bottom: 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnRetinaImage">


</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" id="templateBody" data-template-container>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<![endif]-->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="bodyContainer"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
<tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;">
<!--[if mso]>
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if mso]>
<td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<![endif]-->
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
<tbody><tr>

<td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;">

<p style="text-align: left;"><strong><span style="font-size:24px">{{ __('emails.greeting') }}  {{ $booking->first_name }} {{ $booking->last_name }}!</span></strong><br>
<br>
{{ __('emails.booking_cancelled_message', ['booking_id' => $booking->id]) }}<br>
<br>
@if($refund_status)
@if(!$booking->invoice->is_partial == 1 && $booking->invoice->is_paid == 0)
    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->is_partial ? $booking->invoice->amount_paid : }} was refunded via {{ $booking->invoice->payment_method }}. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@else

    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->amount_paid }} was not refundable. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@endif
@endif
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;">

<p style="text-align: left;"><strong><span style="font-size:24px">{{ __('emails.greeting') }}  {{ $booking->first_name }} {{ $booking->last_name }}!</span></strong><br>
<br>
{{ __('emails.booking_cancelled_message', ['booking_id' => $booking->id]) }}<br>
<br>
@if($refund_status) 
@if(!$booking->invoice->is_paid == 1 && $booking->invoice->is_partial == 0)

    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->is_paid ? $booking->invoice->amount : }} was refunded via {{ $booking->invoice->payment_method }}. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@else

    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->amount }} was not refundable. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@endif
@endif
<br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<!--[if mso]>
</td>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if mso]>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnDividerBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
<tbody class="mcnDividerBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="min-width: 100%; padding: 18px 18px 25px;">
<table class="mcnDividerContent" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;border-top: 2px solid #EAEAEA;">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<span></span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<!--
<td class="mcnDividerBlockInner" style="padding: 18px;">
<hr class="mcnDividerContent" style="border-bottom-color:none; border-left-color:none; border-right-color:none; border-bottom-width:0; border-left-width:0; border-right-width:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0;" />
-->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" id="templateFooter" data-template-container>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<![endif]-->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="templateContainer">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="footerContainer"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnFollowBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
<tbody class="mcnFollowBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:9px" class="mcnFollowBlockInner">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnFollowContentContainer" style="min-width:100%;">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="center" style="padding-left:9px;padding-right:9px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width:100%;" class="mcnFollowContent">
<tbody><tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:9px; padding-right:9px; padding-left:9px;">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                    <![endif]-->

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->

                    @if(config('settings.facebook_link'))<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked" style="display:inline;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                <a href="{{ config('settings.facebook_link', '#') }}" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-facebook-96.png" alt="Facebook" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>@endif


                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    <![endif]-->

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->

                    @if(config('settings.twitter_link'))<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked" style="display:inline;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                <a href="{{ config('settings.twitter_link', '#') }}" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-twitter-96.png" alt="Twitter" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>@endif


                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    <![endif]-->

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->

                    @if(config('settings.instagram_link'))<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked" style="display:inline;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                <a href="{{ config('settings.instagram_link', '#') }}" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-instagram-96.png" alt="Link" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>@endif


                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    <![endif]-->

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->

                    @if(config('settings.google_plus_link'))<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnFollowStacked" style="display:inline;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="mcnFollowIconContent" style="padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:9px;">
                                <a href="{{ config('settings.google_plus_link', '#') }}" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/color-googleplus-96.png" alt="Google Plus" class="mcnFollowBlockIcon" width="48" style="width:48px; max-width:48px; display:block;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>@endif


                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    <![endif]-->

                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;">
<tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="padding-top:9px;">
<!--[if mso]>
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
<tr>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if mso]>
<td valign="top" width="600" style="width:600px;">
<![endif]-->
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
<tbody><tr>

<td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;">

{{ __('emails.spam_notice') }}<br>
<br>
<em>{{ __('auth.copyrights') }}. &copy; {{ date('Y') }}. {{ __('auth.rights_reserved') }} {{ config('settings.business_name', 'Bookify') }}.</em>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<!--[if mso]>
</td>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if mso]>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code with the nested IF statements:

```
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:100%; min-width:100%;" width="100%" class="mcnTextContentContainer">
<tbody><tr>

<td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;">

<p style="text-align: left;"><strong><span style="font-size:24px">{{ __('emails.greeting') }}  {{ $booking->first_name }} {{ $booking->last_name }}!</span></strong><br>
<br>
{{ __('emails.booking_cancelled_message', ['booking_id' => $booking->id]) }}<br>
<br>
@if($refund_status)
@if(!$booking->invoice->is_partial == 1 && $booking->invoice->is_paid == 0)
    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->is_partial ? $booking->invoice->amount_paid : }} was refunded via {{ $booking->invoice->payment_method }}. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@else

    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->amount_paid }} was not refundable. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@endif
@endif
<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-left:18px;">

<p style="text-align: left;"><strong><span style="font-size:24px">{{ __('emails.greeting') }}  {{ $booking->first_name }} {{ $booking->last_name }}!</span></strong><br>
<br>
{{ __('emails.booking_cancelled_message', ['booking_id' => $booking->id]) }}<br>
<br>
@if($refund_status) 
@if(!$booking->invoice->is_paid == 1 && $booking->invoice->is_partial == 0)

    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->is_paid ? $booking->invoice->amount : }} was refunded via {{ $booking->invoice->payment_method }}. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@else

    Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->amount }} was not refundable. If you have any questions, please contact
    us.

@endif
@endif
<br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: have you checked your error log?

Comment: @Tschallacka I did. If I remove the IF statements and change if works? Not sure what the issue is.
`
@if($refund_status) Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->amount }} was refunded via {{ $booking->invoice->payment_method }}. If you have any questions, please contact us. @else Your payment of ${{ $booking->invoice->amount }} was not refundable. If you have any questions, please contact us. @endif 
`